# Ajax call on success not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, encryption

I have to convert a encrypted data response back to plain text.

For this I am using a ajax post call to get the data response and than on sucess passing that data response a decrypto function and getting back the response in plain text (this is the idea)

Now, when I created a Ajax post call and than passing that decrypto their on success nothing is happening

I am sure my decrypto is working

Here is working fiddle for that

https://jsfiddle.net/yktup39e/

Now, problem is in the Ajax. I have only once make an Ajax call so I pretty much sure there will problem in that. But I am not getting that.

This is my code-

JS -

```
$('#action-button').click(function() {
    var settings = {
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://192.168.168.76:8080/HTMLPortingNewService/GetData?ChartName=widget3LineChart&lob=M&carrier=0&enrollmenttype=0&state=0&agent=0&fromdate=04%2F03%2F2015&todate=05%2F03%2F2015&requestID=499F6BF5E4610454A887AB37AF0814E8",
    method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "ac20a050-a8c8-6d58-4350-66141d519394",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      data: {
        "username": "aHRtbHVzZXIx",
        "password": "SHRtbDIwMTY="
      }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
        decrypted = decryptByDES(response,DES);
      console.log(decrypted);
    });
});

function decryptByDES(cipherTextString, keyString) {
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyString);

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(cipherTextString)
    }, keyHex, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    alert(decrypted);

    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

HTML -

```
<script src="tripledes.js"></script>
<script src="mode-ecb.js"></script>


<button id="action-button">Click me to load info!</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Can anyone please help me with that??

Comment: Are you receiving the request on your Backend? And what is the response status code in the network tab of your developer tools?

Comment: It is not giving any response

Comment: $ is not defined is the error

Comment: You have to include jquery library, if your error is `$ is not defined`

Comment: where is your jquery library?

Comment: he missed jquery library

Comment: For any jQuery related function to work, jQuery library needs to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include jquery in your page.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
```